# iperf TCP much faster than UDP, why?

Tags: tcp, udp, iperf

I am wondering why iperf shows much better performance in TCP than UDP. This question is very similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/925294/why-is-iperf-udp-bandwidth-so-much-lower-that-iperf-tcp) one.

UDP should be much faster than TCP because there are no acknowledge and congestion detection. I am looking for an explanation.

### UDP (807 MBits/sec)

```
$ iperf -u -c 127.0.0.1 -b10G
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 127.0.0.1, UDP port 5001
Sending 1470 byte datagrams
UDP buffer size:  208 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 127.0.0.1 port 52064 connected with 127.0.0.1 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   962 MBytes   807 Mbits/sec
[  3] Sent 686377 datagrams
[  3] Server Report:
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec   960 MBytes   805 Mbits/sec   0.004 ms 1662/686376 (0.24%)
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  1 datagrams received out-of-order
```

### TCP (26.7 Gbits/sec)

```
$ iperf -c 127.0.0.1
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 127.0.0.1, TCP port 5001
TCP window size: 2.50 MByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 127.0.0.1 port 60712 connected with 127.0.0.1 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  31.1 GBytes  26.7 Gbits/sec
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're using the old iperf version 2.0.5 which has known performance problems with UDP.  I'd suggest a [2.0.10](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf2/?source=navbar) version.

**iperf -v** will give the version

*Note 1:  The primary issue in 2.0.5 associated with this problem is due to mutex contention between the client thread and the reporter thread.  The shared memory between these two threads was increased to address the issue.*

*Note 3:  There are other performance related enhancements in 2.0.10.*

Bob

Comment: This answer is not valid. I suffer the same behaviour in Iperf3

Answer (score 7):

The default length of UDP datagrams is 1470 bytes. You probably need to increase the length with the -l parameter. For 26Gb/s I'd try something like 50000 for your -l parameter and go up or down from there

You also probably need to add a space between your '-b10G' so that it knows 10G is the value to use for the -b parameter. Also I believe the capital G means GigaBYTES. Your maximum achievable bandwidth with a TCP test is 26 GigaBITS which isnt anywhere close to 10GB. I would make your -b parameter value 26g, with a lower-case g.

Answer (score -1):

> UDP should be much faster than TCP because there are no acknowledge and congestion detection.

That will mostly depending on what you are looking to do. If you need to transfer files between two end-points in the Internet, unless you manually implement a reliable transmission mechanism on UDP at the application level, you will want to use TCP.

In my opinion, it does not make much sense to do a pure UDP bandwidth test with iPerf, as essentially it just results in iPerf trying to put packets on the wire as fast as possible. I would suggest using it for generating UDP flows with a constant data rate, in order to roughly measure what would happen to UDP traffic, such as VoIP, in your network.

Comment: This is not the answer to this question

Answer (score -1):

TCP is helped with various hadware offloads such as tso/gro where as UDP is not helped by any of those offloads as they don't apply on udp datagrams.